# Problem with blank submitted values and returned mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'ilhan', 'password123');
if(!$link)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db("metu", $link);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

if(isset($_POST["email"])) // AND strlen($_POST["email"])>1 solves the problem
//  but I didn't get why the page is redirected...
    {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

        if (!$result)
            {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }

        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($row['password'] == $password) 
            {
                $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $row['id'];
                mysql_close($link);
                header("Location: http://www.example.com");
            }
        else $login = false;


        mysql_close($link);
    }
else $login = false;
?>
```

Do you think that the page will be redirected if the user submits a blank email and blank password? It shouldn't but the page is redirected. Why is that? Bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've overlooked the issue at first.
here it is:

```
if($row['password'] == $password)
```

empty `$row['password']` is equal to empty `$password`. evaluated to `true`

here is what I'd do it

```
<?php
include 'db.php';    
if(isset($_POST["email"]))
{
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='%s' AND password='%s'";
    $id  = dbGetOne($sql,$_POST["email"],MD5($_POST["email"].$_POST["password"]));
    if($id) 
    {
        $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $row['id'];
        header("Location: http://www.example.com");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that blank is not "not set" but what does mysql return as password? and what is the corresponding line of of blank in my table so that it returns the blank password? it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(isset($_POST["email"])) 
 // AND strlen($_POST["email"])>1 solves the problem 
 // but I didn't get why the page is redirected...
```

if $_POST["email"] is empty string -> isset will return true

EDIT: add `if ( isset($_POST["email"]) && isset ($_POST["password"]) )` to avoid empty passwords and make sure that `$row` is not empty when `if($row['password'] == $password)'

Comment: I know and then it shouldn't pass the if($row['password'] == $password). The redirection is within it.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_num_rows function to find then umber of rows returned. mysql_query will return FALSE on error but in your case, your SQL is still a valid SQL if email is blank. It will just return an empty result set.